# Gauss Seidel Method to solve Linear equations in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve a linear algebraic equation using Gauss-seidel method in python but cannot seem to find the error here. The equation i am trying to write along with my code is attached in the image below.
Thank you.

Gauss-seidel Equation:
[image: Gauss-seidel Equation]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
A= np.array([4.,-1.,1.,-1.,4.,-2.,1.,-2.,4.]).reshape(3,3)
B= np.array([12.,-1.,5.]).reshape(3,1)
N= len(B)
print (N)
x=np.zeros(N)
xold= np.array([10.,10.,10.]).reshape(3,1)
tol=0.01
x=np.array([5.,5.,5.]).reshape(3,1)
#for i in range (N):
#    print ("start at i=",i, "and xi=",x[i])
temp=0
while (abs(x[0]-xold[0])>tol):
    xold=x
    print ("absstart=",abs(x-xold))####
    for i in range (N):
        for j in range (N):
            if j!= i:
                temp+=A[i,j]*x[j]
        #print ("temp=",temp)####
        x[i]=(1/A[i,i])*(B[i]-temp)
        #print ("end at x",i,"=",x[i])####
        #print ("abs= ",abs(x-xold))####
    print (x)
    print (xold)
```

Comment: The Wikipedia page for Gauss-Seidel gives a Python implementation.  Have you compared your code against it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because this line of code

```
temp = 0
```

is not at the right place.

Isn't it supposed to be reset to zero at each iteration of i?